# Powershell sql queries

Tags: sql-server-2005, powershell-2.0

I am new to powershell and trying to built a script which can accept username and fetch corresponding userID from table(SUser), based on which i should delete that particular user from that table.
Below is the code, kindly correct in case of any syntax errors cause i am not able to find any error and

**I am not able to fetch values properly. Some times the query doesnt fetch values and some times the results on first run are displayed on the second run.**

```
clear
$servername = "Someserver"
$databasename = "someDB"
$c = Get-Credential

$cmd1 = "select UserID from SUser where UserName='$Name'"
$cmd2 = "delete from SUser where UserID = '$a'"

$connectionString = [string]::Format( "server={0};database={1};uid={2};pwd=    {3};Integrated     Security=True;", "$servername", "$databasename",$c.username,$c.GetNetworkCredential    ().password)

$conn = New-Object system.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
$conn.connectionstring = $connectionString
$conn.open()
switch ($conn.State)
{
"Open"  
    { 
        $SqlCmd1 = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand
        $SqlCmd1.CommandText = $cmd1
        $SqlCmd1.Connection = $Conn

        $Name = Read-host "Enter UserName (One user name at a time):"
        write-host "UserName Entered:" $Name
        $usrname = $SqlCmd1.ExecuteScalar()
        $a = $usrname
        write-host "User Id for Username $Name :"$a


        $SqlCmd2 = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand    
        $SqlCmd2.CommandText = $cmd2
        $SqlCmd2.Connection = $Conn

        $usrid = $SqlCmd2.ExecuteScalar()

     }
Default 
     { Write-Host "The connection is $($conn.State)"; 
     }
 }
$conn.close()
```

Thanks,
Hari

Comment: What do you get when you add a `write-host $SqlCmd1.CommandText` and `write-host $SqlCmd2.CommandText` before you execute them?

Comment: Actually I was using another select statement instead of a delete for $cmd2 at top for testing 

`$cmd2 = "select UserName from SUser where UserID='$a'"`

I am getting the below lines in the ouput pane: 

`select UserID from SUser where UserName='' `
`select UserName from SUser where UserID=''`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that you asign `$cmd1` when the variable `$Name` is not yet set. Variable expansion does not work like a templateing mechanism in Powershell. So you have to change

```
$SqlCmd1.CommandText = $cmd1
```

to

```
$SqlCmd1.CommandText = "select UserID from SUser where UserName='$Name'"
```

in your script (the same applies for `$SqlCmd1`).

BTW: Your script is prone to SQL Injection!

Comment: Thanks a lot. Works fine :) 

Its just an internal purpose script.

Comment: It doesn't matter what the "purpose" of the script is. **Always** code defensively.

Comment: Hi, The above code will ask for User Credentials for loging in. **But even with improper(incorrect) credentials, i am able to log into DB. and execute quieries** Any problem with connection string ?

Comment: Could you please make that a new question, because I cannot (currently) reproduce your problem. Maybe with some simplified code?

Comment: Here is the link for my new question : 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20403707/getting-login-to-sql-server-2005-with-invalid-credentials