# getting login to SQL Server 2005 with invalid credentials

Tags: sql-server-2005, powershell-2.0

The purpose of script is to log into a remote SQLSERVER and execute a query.
I used the below code to to ask for credentials and when the connection is open i will check using **$conn.state** , when its open i have to execute queries.

Even when i give invalid credentials, the control is going into **Switch --> Open block** and getting the statement out **Logged in.The connection is Open**.

```
clear
$servername = "Someserver";$databasename = "someDB";$c = Get-Credential

$connectionString = [string]::Format( "server={0};database={1};uid={2};pwd=   {3};Integrated  Security=True;", "$servername", "$databasename",$c.username,$c.GetNetworkCredential().password)

$conn = New-Object system.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
$conn.connectionstring = $connectionString
$conn.open()

switch ($conn.State)
{
  "Open"{ write-host "Logged in.The connection is $($conn.State)"}
   Default{ Write-Host "The connection is $($conn.State).Error connecting db."; }
}

$conn.close()
```